# Kasparov quote on boldness

Tags: kasparov, quotations

I am looking for a Kasparov quote on boldness. I would like to be something along the lines of this: "I do less tactical training as tournament time approaches. Instead, I do more bold, daring things."

Comment: @Rewan it's not correct.

Answer (score 4):

I found a few in an article on chessworld.com called ["31 Great Chess Quotes from Garry Kasparov."](https://thechessworld.com/articles/general-information/31-great-chess-quotes-from-garry-kasparov-new/)

> “When your house is on fire, you can’t be bothered with the neighbors. Or, as we say in chess, if your King is under attack, don’t worry about losing a pawn on the queenside.”

> “If you wish to succeed, you must brave the risk of failure.”

> “The highest art of the chessplayer lies in not allowing your opponent to show you what he can do.”